# Error 4024 structured Text programming

Tags: plc, structured-text

```
IF  IP_emo:=FALSE THEN
    State:= OFF_Mode;
ELSE
    State :=OFF AND  IP_emo:=TRUE AND start_Btn:=TRUE OR start_Btn:=False;
    State:= Monitor_Mode;
END_IF
```

I am not sure why I am getting error 4024 on this code requiring `a := before "THEN"`.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Not sure what plc you are using or what error 4024 means but I can comment on the format of your code if you use a typcicaly IEC 61131 plc language (which most plcs are).

First, the `:=` i an assignment operator.  The `=` is a comparison operator.  So in your `if` statment you would use

```
IF IP_emo = FALSE THEN
```

or alternatively (depending on which plc you use.  typically all IEC 61131 languages are the same though)

```
IF NOT IP_emo THEN
```

Secondly, `AND` and `OR` are for comparison so you can't have them with an assingment operator.  You can do something like

```
ELSE
   State :=OFF;
   IP_emo:=TRUE; 
   start_Btn:=TRUE; 
   start_Btn:=FALSE;
   State:= Monitor_Mode;
END_IF
```

or maybe

```
 ELSE
   State :=OFF;
      IF IP_emo=TRUE AND start_Btn=TRUE AND (start_Btn=TRUE OR start_Btn=FALSE) THEN
          State:= Monitor_Mode;
      END_IF
END_IF
```

not exactly sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what PLC or tool you are using, what the error 4024 means and which line it comes from. That makes it a little hard to answer your question. Some would probably say that the question qualifies for a down-wote on that account.

I'm a little confused by the formatting of your example. Please format as code (done automatically, if you use 4 spaces indent) and it will be easier to read and answer.

I made an attempt at formatting below, and have some comments to that.

- Line 1: Normally you wouldn't use := but only = before THEN (might
  depend on the compiler, but I doubt it)
- Line 4: There's too many :='s. Should this line and the following maybe have been split into some ELSIF's or another nested IF?

I hope that helps. :-)

```
IF IP_emo:=FALSE THEN
  State:= OFF_Mode;
ELSE
  State :=OFF AND IP_emo:=TRUE AND start_Btn:=TRUE OR start_Btn:=FALSE;
  State:= Monitor_Mode;
END_IF
```